# How can I filter SearchQuerySet results based on a specifice model and an ID

Tags: python, django-haystack, searchqueryset

This is the model, in which I want to search

```
class itemType(models.Model):
  partNumber = models.CharField(max_length = 12, null = True)
  designation = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
  timeCreate = models.DateTimeField() #auto update field, done in save method
  timeEdit = models.DateTimeField() #auto update field, done in save method
```

This is the view, I want to use to prepare my results

```
def itemtypedetails(request, itemtype_id):
  result = SearchQuerySet.models(itemType)
  #how can I filter the ID??
  return render_to_response('itemtypedetails.html', locals())
```

What I want is that my results are based on the model (itemType) and the ID of an itemType (itemtype_id). 


I don't understand how to combine these two *filters*.

thanks for helping

Comment: i think it gonna be helpful for you and to learn more if you can take time to check things on :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use .filter('your condition here')

```
result = SearchQuerySet.filter(ID=7).models(itemType)
```

Comment: For me this worked only when ID was lowercase, i.e.: `result = SearchQuerySet.filter(id=7).models(itemType)`